# Tech-related: should I capitalize the word 'Git' in this context or not?

Tags: capitalization, technical, programming, tech-writing

Which one is proper: the one with 'Git' capitalized or the one without?

1. Configure git commit signing. or
2. Configure Git commit signing.

Comment: Is Git supposed to be a shortened (familiar abbreviation by aficionados) of [**GitHub**](https://github.com/)? If so, capitalise it, or use its proper name. A [git](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/git) is an unpleasant/stupid person.

Comment: @WeatherVane GitHub is a website built to work with [Git](https://git-scm.com/), a local command line tool to keep track of file changes while coding.

Comment: @Laurel it's still not **git**.

Comment: If you're running it as a command, it *is* `git` (so, for example `git switch -`, `git commit -m"..."`, `git log`).

Comment: @Laurel it might be a techie question, but surely it's still [**Git**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611711/tech-related-should-i-capitalize-the-word-git-in-this-context-or-not#comment1550221_611711) and not a discussion about computer command line syntax.

Comment: I'm talking about GitHub, yes. So, I guess the second one is the correct in this case.

Comment: In this context I'm not talking about the command line command. Rather, about the signing of commits with GPG to prove their authenticity.

Comment: In English *Git* is a proper noun — the name of an application; capitalize it. In code, follow the required syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, I suggest treating it as regular text and capitalizing it but in other cases it might be more appropriate to leave it lowercase as a command.

- Git is the name of the software and a proper noun, and it is written as such on [its website](https://git-scm.com/): "The advantages of **Git** compared to other source control systems." Likewise, *commits* are a concept in Git but that's not a proper noun so it's lowercase.
- `git` is what you run on the command line to use that software. This is always lowercase (I have never seen a command like that which wasn't), and I've stylized it as code so it's clear it's a command. This is the formatting you would use if you were quoting a command.

To put this into practice with an example (which I know is somewhat nonsensical from a technical standpoint):

- Signing amended Git commits (not a command, and for example uses the plural *commits* so you cannot execute it)
- Signing with `git commit --amend` (a command that you can execute as part of this hypothetical process)

Comment: Thank you. So, in this case "Configure Git commit signing" is okay. Am I right?

Comment: Yes..............